# the diagonal angle between a theta and phi vector and the x axis as well as the derivative

Tags: vector-analysis

[image]

Find `w`, the angle ∠`rox`.  That is, the angle from the red vector `r` to the positive `x` axis, in terms of `u` and `v`.

Also find the derivative of `w` when neither `u` nor `v` are held constant but instead are held to remain proportional.  That is, doubling `u` will double `v`.

This is seeking to prove or disprove that if `u` and `v` are held proportional to each other that `w` changes with them, proportionally.

Answer (score 1):

We can directly project vector $ \vec or $ on positive $x-$ axis as

$$ \cos \angle rox  =(\cos v \cos u) $$

It is in effect the same when we take dot product of vectors

$$ \vec {ox}= (\cos v \cos u,0,0);\; \vec {or} = (\cos v \cos u,\cos v \sin u,\sin v) $$

$$\cos w_1=\cos ∠rox =\dfrac{(\cos v \cos u)^2+0+0}{(\cos v \cos u)\cdot (1) }=\cos v \cos u $$

$$\cos w_2=\cos 2v \cos 2u.$$

If $ v=um,$  then $ (\cos m v \cos u)$ is not proportional to $ (\cos v \cos u) $.

For the double angles

If e.g., $ u=v=\pi/3, \cos w_1=\dfrac14; \cos w_2= \dfrac14 $ which does not even change.

There can be no linearity or proportionality with circular trigonometric ratios products. Can be also confirmed by graphing the two cosines.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, $\,\cos ∠rox = \frac{r\cos v \cos u}{r}=\cos v \cos u$